# Why Can't Chrome Reliably Load 3 Simple Audio Files?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

**The Problem:** Audio files frequently fail to load. As in they do not even show up under the "Network" tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

**Test Case:**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
['audio1.ogg', 'audio2.ogg', 'audio3.ogg'].forEach((path) => {
    new Audio(path);
});
```

Audio Files:

- https://github.com/Joncom/chrome-audio-bug/raw/master/audio1.ogg
- https://github.com/Joncom/chrome-audio-bug/raw/master/audio2.ogg
- https://github.com/Joncom/chrome-audio-bug/raw/master/audio3.ogg

**Steps To Reproduce:**

1. Open new tab in Chrome browser
2. Open "Dev Tools"
3. Select "Network" tab
4. Open test case "index.html" in current tab
5. See "Explanation" and then refresh as needed

**Explanation:**

- The first time you load the test case, you will notice all 3 audio files show up in the "Network" tab. They will all start and finish loading successfully.
- However upon refreshing, likely none of the audio files will show up or be loaded again.
- Strangely, by waiting a good minute or two, the issue temporarily vanishes, and the next refresh will load all audio files correctly again.
- But after that, loads will fail as before.

Comment: What you describe looks a lot like client-side caching. Can the audio files still be played despite not appearing in the Network tab? How are those files served from your server?

Comment: I see you've come back and edited the question, but you haven't answered @FrédéricHamidi's question. Why not?

Comment: I can replicate them not showing up in the Network tab (even with the **Disable Cache** flag set), but the files **do** load and play correctly when I ask them to, even when not listed.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, the audio files can still be played despite not appearing in the Network tab! So I guess this is completely normal behavior then?

Comment: I can replicate the same apparent issue in chrome AND firefox - and I concur with T.J.Crowder - the audio is playable regardless

Comment: Yes, I think I just mistook this behavior for a problem, because I'm seeing an HTML5 video game frequently get stuck at the "preloading" phase, and it seems these audio files are to blame, because removing them fixes the issue. Gonna dig some more and maybe open a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate them not showing up in the Network tab (even with the **Disable Cache** flag set), but the files do load and play correctly — *most* of the time.

> Yes, I think I just mistook this behavior for a problem, because I'm seeing an HTML5 video game frequently get stuck at the "preloading" phase, and it seems these audio files are to blame, because removing them fixes the issue.

I discovered that if I do what's in your test case, just creating the `Audio` object but *not* adding it to the DOM, *usually* I got `canplay` events from them, but not always — about one in ten times one, two, or even all three of them wouldn't fire `canplay`. But if I appended them to the DOM, I always got the `canplay` event.

So if you're not adding them to the DOM (just `document.body.appendChild(new Audio(path));` is enough), that could be the cause of your preloading-never-ending issue.

Comment: Yes, your findings about the `canplaythrough` event not firing seems to be the real problem (not showing up in the Network tab seems to just be a red herring). Your `appendChild` solution does indeed fix the test case, so I will mark this correct. However, it doesn't seem to be enough to fix the same issue (events not always firing) for my HTML5 game, so I will have to keep digging...

Comment: Just an afterthought: Being forced to append a clip to the DOM just to make it reliable seems like a hack more than a best practice, which makes me feel an little uneasy.

Comment: For anyone interested, follow-up up research here: http://impactjs.com/forums/impact-engine/bug-report-chrome-reliably-fails-to-load-audio